# dynamycally created element click event inside jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins, click

I'm trying to make an autocomplete plugin with jQuery. Currently I did this:     http://jsfiddle.net/2rpn5L29/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="input" value=""></div>
```

JS:

```
(function ( $ ) {
  $.fn.searchPlugin = function( options ) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this), data = options.data, search = $this.val().toLowerCase(), result = [];

      function get(arg) {
        result = [];
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
          if(data[i]['name'].toLowerCase().indexOf(arg)!=-1) {
            result.push(data[i]);
          }
          /*
            for(key in data[i]) {
                if(data[i][key].indexOf(search)!=-1) {
                results.push(data[i]);
              }
            }
         */
        }
      }

      function getById(id) {
        return result[id].name;
      }

      function set() {
        if(!$this.next('.autocomplete').length) {
          $this.after('<div class="autocomplete"></div>');
        }else {
          $this.next('.autocomplete').html('');
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          $this.next('.autocomplete').append('<div class="autocomplete__item" data-id="' + i + '">' + result[i].name + '</div>');
        }
      }

      $this.on('change keyup', function(){
        get( $this.val().toLowerCase() );
        set( result );
      });

      $this.on('blur', function(){
        //$this.next('.autocomplete').html('');
      });


      $('.form-group').on('click', '.autocomplete__item', function(e){
        alert( getById( $(this).data('id') ) );
        $this.val( getById( $(this).data('id') ) );
        $this.next('.autocomplete').html('');
      });
    });
  };
}( jQuery ));
$(function(){
  var data = [{'id': 1,'name': 'USA'},{'id': 2,'name': 'France'},{'id': 3,'name': 'Italy'}];

  $('.input').searchPlugin({
    data: data
  });
});
```

When you type `USA` inside the input field and than you click on the text which appeared, it should alert the selected text. But it only work on the second click, not on the first. How can I fire the click event on the first click?

This is the code section which sould alert the selected text:

```
$('.form-group').on('click', '.autocomplete__item', function(e){
    alert( getById( $(this).data('id') ) );
    $this.val( getById( $(this).data('id') ) );
    $this.next('.autocomplete').html('');
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `change` from `$this.on('change keyup', function(){`.

Since you update the suggestions on `keyup`, the `change` isn't really usefull anyway.

When user leaves the input to `click` on a suggestion, this `change` handler triggers first and changes the suggested elements (for the same thing, yes...)

Still the `click` event, which happens after the `change` event, but before new elements are created by the `change`... was triggered on the old *not present anymore* elements, not on the new ones.

;)